# Why do people ask when does life start?

Tags: abortion

Abortion opponents and free choicer apparently ask this question and what has it got to do with abortion. All the opponent has to say is bacteria is alive and sperm and ovuum is alive and what does this question have to do with abortion and they win the argument immediately. Are you going to fight to protect bacteria? If people want to say when does human life start then science has very scant evidence and it is still judgement call about what human life means.

Comment: Sounds more like philosophical question, then political one.

Comment: It does not sound like a question at all, honestly. The first part is based on the wrong assumption that people are debating the start of any life (as opposed to human life) and the second part seems to be "Why do people debate a judgement call?" which answers itself.

Comment: The question they are REALLY (indirectly) asking is "When do human rights start?" the term "life" is just used as a proxy for that.

Comment: @JohnFx Then that raises the question: why do anti-abortion rights activists insist on using misleading/dishonest phrasing that deliberately obfuscates the issue?

Comment: @xyldke "people are debating the start of any life (as opposed to human life)" See my response to JohnFx.

Comment: How is this not a Politics question? There are political reasons for anti-abortion rights activists using the language they do.

Comment: @accumulation Yesterday - Firstly, I can't say why other people use any specific wording. Secondly, The pro-life movement is not a single hive-mind. It is made of up individuals who may or may not use that phrase, and if they do they may have different reasons.  Thirdly, it is unfair to say it DELIBERATELY obfuscates the issue. It doesn't it just isn't the most precise way to describe their views, but is far more succinct and easier to put on a protest sign.  It's simply a non-nuanced way to make their point. Assuming they are acting in bad faith is a strawman argument.

Comment: Politics is the art of convincing people whether one on one or groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motivation *answering* the question is that it makes specific argument around abortion policy much easier to make. A clear-cut simple answer gives a simple result when answering questions about the right and wrong of abortion policy. If full human life begins at conception, then abortion is murder; if it begins at birth or late in pregnancy, then abortion is far less objectionable.

But, in reality, few are genuinely *asking* the question. They have already picked a side in the debate on abortion and are seeking an easy answer that justifies their chosen position.

A serious scientifically informed answer would be uncomfortable (possibly for either side) as it would deny that there is any possibility of reaching a clear-cut, black or white answer. The biological reality is messy and admits that *grey* is a possible answer not just black or white. That leaves the morality of abortion question as a matter of judgement, weighing up different issues and specific circumstances. Especially in the USA this is not an answer that advocates on either side are happy with, most seeming to prefer the answer to be black or white.

Answer (score 14):

You pretty much answered your own question...

It's more "When does HUMAN life start". a sperm cell isn't human yet... an Embroy isn't human yet according to pro choice while pro life say it is.

How far in the pregnancy can you consider the embryo a real human baby?

- when the embryo is formed?
- when it has a heart beat?
- when it is able to live outside of the mother?
- when it draws first breath?

Although science can give indicators of the stage the "organism" is in, it is mainly opinion based what stage can be considered a living human or not.

Besides the question around abortion, it also raises the questions of unplanned loss...

When a pregnant woman is assaulted and loses the baby, is it murder? just part of the assault? or "damage of property"? Or if the woman loses the baby due to an accident or bad living habits... is it child neglect/endangerment? Should she be prosecuted for it?

Comment: My question is not when does life begin or human beings begin but why people ask this bizarre irrelevant question.

Comment: @user2617804 because of the legal implications... if the human is alive it is murder, if it is not alive it's not. So people debate when it is considered alive or not for that reason. That is the question they are asking.

Comment: @user2617804: Why do you think the distinction between "cutting away some cells" and "murdering a human being" is irrelevant?

Answer (score 13):

The science is not the point. The point is the legal implication around the question.

If you subscribe to the values of [Universal Declaration of Human Right](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/universal-declaration-of-human-rights), you are confronted with the notion that human beings possess "dignity" which is basically special rights that are considered priceless and inalienable. Among these rights are "right to life".

Once you operate in this legal realm, the question of "When does life start?" becomes extremely high-stakes.

But I think the question is poorly phrased.

People are not actually interested in when does life start - we can all look at cells multiply under a microscope, there's no mystery there. What they are really asking is when does "personhood" start.

**Human dignity is a legal concept, so it necessarily must follow legal personhood as defined by law, not life as observed by science.**

Most countries mark the beginning of personhood somewhere between the moment of conception to the moment the infant takes its first breath. It is within that timeframe where countries decide when an embryo becomes a person, it comes down to value, not science.

Comment: Have never seen a video where they ask this vague question- easy to search Youtube for this irrelevant question?

Comment: And you have to confront when do you become a human being?

Comment: @user2617804 I'm getting the sense that you think this is a simple problem with simple solution?

Comment: No, your answer is like it is simple.  Some video include microsopic cell multiplication and  conception.

Comment: If you say "when does personhood start?" the pro-lifer comes back with "why do you care about personhood? It's a living human being!"

Comment: @user253751 Being a human does not guarantee you anything, that has been true for vast majority of human history, principly in an extremely common trade called slavery. It is only when you tie the status of being human with legal personhood that rights are guaranteed. If pro-lifers want to talk about rights, then they should make the legal case for it, because being human alone is not enough.

Comment: @user253751 No, the pro-lifer would say "Conception".  Because personhood is exactly why it matters when life begins.  I get the sense you haven't really looked into the pro-life position very thoroughly.

Comment: @Ryan_L Is there legal merit in looking into pro-life position? It basically boils down to: "I feel X therefore X is right". Society runs on rule of law, not rule of feeling. Unless you can convert feeling into law, they are inconsequential.

Comment: @QuantumWalnut I can say the same about the pro-choice position.  The law is based on a particular moral worldview, and whichever worldview wins politically gets implemented legally.